# Convert JSON array into an insert query string in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, decode

i have a JSON array and i need to convert it into insert query string,
does anyone have idea how to do that?

here's the JSON string

```
$array = '[
   {
     "table":"customer",
     "data":
       [
         {
           "name":"Johny",
           "address":"jl. abc no 5",
           "where" :

             {
               "customerid":1
             }

         },
         {
           "name":"Doko",
           "address":"jl. kerinci 7"
           "where" :

             {
               "customerid":2
             }
         }
       ]
   },
   {
     "table":"supplier",
     "data":
       [
         {
           "id":123
         },
         {
           "id":234
         }
       ]
   }
]
';
```

then i use json_decode to convert it into an array

```
$obj = json_decode($array,true);
```

here's the workaround i've done so far.

```
foreach($obj as $result){
  $table = $result['table'] . "</br>";
  $data =  $result['data'];
  $string = "INSERT INTO $table (";
  foreach($data as $subdata ){
    foreach($subdata as $key=>$val){
      $string .= "$key,";
      $string .= ")VALUES (";
      $string .= "'$val'" . ",";
    }
    $string .= ");";
  }
  echo $string."</br>";
}
```

but it doesn't work like i want to,

what i need is to convert it into query like

```
INSERT INTO customer(customerid,address)values('1','jl.abc no 5');
INSERT INTO customer(customerid,address)values('2','jl. kerinci no 7');
INSERT INTO supplier(id)values('123');
INSERT INTO supplier(id)values('234');
```

thanks in advance.

PS: the array could be more than two arrays or even just one.

===========================================================================

updates : read array then split it into update query string 
like

```
UPDATE customer SET name="JOHNY", address="jl. abc no 5";
UPDATE customer SET name="Doko", address="jl. kerinci 7";
```

when "where" key exists and ignore it when "where" key doesn't exist

Comment: Is this always just two arrays when you decode? the customer and supplier?

Comment: @L.Herrera nope, it could be more than two, or maybe just one.

Comment: but not greater than two? it can be customer only? supplier only?

Comment: no, i want to iterate the array based on the table key then iterate the table key array into a query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the foreach, I first use for statement to iterate first the array, because your json have a combination of index and key value pair. Here it is:

```
    $query = "";
    for($i = 0, $ctr = count($obj); $i < $ctr; $i++) {
        for($x = 0, $ctr_data = count($obj[$i]["data"]); $x < $ctr_data; $x++) {
            $query2 = array(); // After loop cleans the array
            $query .= "INSERT INTO "  . $obj[$i]["table"];
            $query .= "(";
                foreach($obj[$i]["data"][$x] as $key => $value) {
                    $query2[] = $key;
                }
                $query .= implode(",", $query2) . ") VALUES";  // glue the commas

                $query2 = array(); // After the first foreach cleans the array

                foreach($obj[$i]["data"][$x] as $key => $value) {
                    $query2[] = "'$value'";
                }
                $query .= "(";
                $query .= implode(",", $query2) . ") <br>"; // glue the commas
        }
    }

    echo $query;
```

**EDIT:**

1. The first loop counts first the number of array, in your case its two.
2. The second loop counts the array on the key "data".
3. Prepare an array $query2 = array(); so that you will have a container of the values of the key/values on key "data".
4. Get the index "table" name.
5. The third loop is for the key "data" getting its keys.
6. Store the keys on the $query2 for later use.
7. Using implode function, all keys are glued with each other with commas.
8. Prepare again the array $query2 to cleanse the array.
9. The fourth loop is for the key "data" getting its values.
10. Repeat number 6.
11. Repeat number 7.

Comment: works like charms... mind to explain about this further?

Comment: thanks for the help, but now i am facing another problem to convert the array into update string, the question is updated.

Comment: Well, you can derive your UPDATE by re-using this INSERT loop. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create class Database.php to exc query code bellow

```
<?php 
/*
  * Author: luongitvnsoft@gmail.com
    * Language: Vietnamme
    * Site url: http://itvnsoft.com
    * Youtube: Itvnsoft Web Developer
    * Phone:   0986 421 127
    * File Database.php 
    * khai báo các thông tin kết nối database
    * ccs hằng số HOST DB_NAME DB_USER DB_PASS khai bóa bên file config.php
  */
try {
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db->exec("set names utf8");

 function getAll($table,$limit = 10){
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT $limit";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
 }


function insert($table,$data){
    global $db;
    if(isset($data) && is_array($data)){
        $files = array_keys($data);
        $files = implode($files, ',');
        $values = array_values($data);
        $values = implode($values, "','");

        $sql = "Insert Into $table($files) values('$values')";
        // $conn->exec($sql)
        $db->exec($sql);
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}



  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die( "Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

?>
```

Step 2: in your php page handling php json code

```
include 'Database.php';

foreach($obj as $result){
  $table = $result['table'] . "</br>";
  $data =  $result['data'];
  insert($table,$data);
}
```